# VB.NET WindowForms Question

Tags: vb.net, events, hover, gdi

I am looking for a specific custom control. I am drawing some rectangles to my picture box, now I would like to display a tooltip when someone moves his mouse to one of the rectangles, so a hover rectangle-hover event. Does this sound doable at all? If yes, is there anyone that has made such a control already? If no, how would I go about making my own? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this.  You can do some really cool things with this free tooltip library:

http://www.tooltips.net

You can also try the [ToolTip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx) in Windows Forms.

Comment: Hm will take a look at the library later, thanks. Though, can't use the ToolTip class, because the rectangles aren't a control.